# How to get information about process memory from a C program?

Tags: linux

I have to get the memory usage information of a process. I know that it is available in `/proc/${pid}/statm` but is there a system function for obtaining it. Parsing a file seems inefficient.

Comment: It's kind of the Unix philosophy that passing data via human-readable streams/files is better than dedicated API calls with binary data formats and that the efficiency gains of the latter are negligible. For children processes and self, you can use getrusage. For other processes, I think you'll have to make do with the filesystem API, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You are mistaken: Unix philosophy is to provide ASCII text as program output and getrusage() only counts statistics information for dead and awaited already children.

Answer (score 6):

You are mistaken that parsing a file seems inefficient, because you take it out of context. You probably already know that the information under `/proc` is only "created" when you request it, and **not** updated whenever there is a change. So not only do you have to parse it, the kernel has to generate it as text.

Reading a few bytes directly into a long is of course more efficient than calling `atoi()` on a string. But you have to see that as part of the context where you anyway have to do a system call. All the extra code executed to read some file content (or to call some binary API the kernel might provide) dwarfs the time it takes to do the string conversion.

Kernel processes, which need this kind of data much more often than the average program, do not have the overhead of having to do system calls to get to this data and they can access that kind of data directly.

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention what kind of information you like to get, but Linux reimplemented the `pmap <pid>` command from Solaris. It does not print the exact same information but the output is comparable. You may like to check whether Linux reimplemented more from the various p* commands from Solaris. The interesting `psig` is not supported on Linux.

For security reasons, specific information on UNIX is only available to the process itself and what is beyond that is limited and typically only for `ps` and similar programs.

Note that the general UNIX philosophy was to give special information via the `ioctl()` function, this is how `/proc` worked in it's first implementation in the late 1980s. Each process was a file in /proc and only ioctls did work on that file. Note that before /proc was introduced, UNIX users were forced to freely read kernel memory to get special information and as there were no locks, this could result in junk when e.g. the related process died or was swapped out.

In 1980, UNOS - the first UNIX clone implemented a getpsinfo() sycall for the ps command. `/proc` can be seen as a better implementation of an abstract view.

Around the mid 1990s, procfs-2 defined a process to become a directory and files inside allow to read complex binary data (e.g. for `/proc/<pid>/as` the address space file). Other files inside that directory have structured binary data (defined c stuctures) that can be `read()` (e.g. `/proc/<pid>/usage` for the resource usage).

Linux is not compatible to the procfs and procfs2 papers, the path names differ and the file content differs. `/proc/<pid>/fd/`on Linux is in a clear conflict with the AT&T procfs2 paper.